# How to fetch an image to UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Could you please help me to find out where I'm wrong?  I was formulating a screen which can edit the profile picture.. If the file destination in firestore contains image file then I need to keep the same otherwise I want to upload a new file from phone to firestore and keep that as profile picture.

I could not fetch the image stored in fireStrore.  Here is the code I am working on.

The image is uploading in firebase successfully but but I could not fetch it down to UI.

I could not find any useful videos on internet also..

```
class ImageUpload extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageUpload({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageUpload> createState() => _ImageUploadState();
}

class _ImageUploadState extends State<ImageUpload> {
  firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
  File? _photo;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  //get ref => null;

  Future imgFromGallery() async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _photo = File(pickedFile.path);
        uploadFile();
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future imgFromCamera() async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _photo = File(pickedFile.path);
        uploadFile();
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    if (_photo == null) return;

    final fileName = basename(_photo!.path);
    final destination = 'profile/profilePic$user';

    try {
      final ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref(destination)
          .child('$user/');
      //await ref.delete();
      await ref.putFile(_photo!);
    } catch (e) {
      print('error occured');
    }
  }

  Future getImage() async {}

  //uploadFile(fileName);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      try {
        final ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref('profile/profilePic$user')
            .child('$user/')
            .getDownloadURL()
            .toString();
        _photo = File(ref);
      } catch (e) {
        _photo = null;
      }
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 32,
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _showPicker(context);
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 55,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xffFDCF09),
                child: _photo != null
                    ? ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        child: Image.file(
                          _photo!,
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[200],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.camera_alt,
                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                        ),
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showPicker(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              child: Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                      title: const Text('Gallery'),
                      onTap: () {
                        imgFromGallery();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                    title: const Text('Camera'),
                    onTap: () {
                      imgFromCamera();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide ref what you are getting in ref variable.

Comment: Instance of 'Future<String>'

Answer (score 0):

Put `await` before `firebaseStorage` like this.

```
final ref = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref('profile/profilePic$user')
            .child('$user/')
            .getDownloadURL()
            .toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we store our images in fire storage. So, whenever we've to retrieve an image we retrieve url from storage using this code.

```
Future<void> getImageUrl() async {
 imageUrl= await FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child("Flutter.png")
    .getImageUrl();
}
```